What is preventing a wingsuit with rotors from being made?
This is probably the wrong place to ask, and if so, I apologize, but I was wondering, what are the roadblocks to making a powered wingsuit?
If we look at something like the Vulture from the MCU, is the problem the power source, material weight, or wingspan? Or is it a combination of all three? If we had a suitable power source, could we feasibly construct a similar mechanism?
Again, sorry if this is the wrong place, but I was looking for more realistic answers for a novel I'm working on.

Gravity Industries has made a small-scale version with a few small jet engines.. you can check that out. And for more mythical questions use World Building SE

What specifications are you working from, that you think this HAS NOT already been done?

When does a powered wingsuit stop being a wingsuit?

@DJClayworth, when the body is no longer structural, and flight control is performed by manipulating control surfaces vs twisting and shifting the body.

Closely related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91555/are-there-retractable-compact-hang-gliders/91557#91557

Well, they already have. Yvette Rossy developed a jet powered wingsuit a number of years ago.
The chief downside to this design is the inability to land without a recovery parachute on the user.  VTOL models are, apparently, not yet available.
Jet packs and rocket belts have been around for the past 60 years in one former or another, and typically limited by fuel supply and control difficulties in flight.  Gravity industries is coming very close to a product for mass market using micro-sized jet engines for propulsion.  Another example are electrically powered quad copter platforms, which allow for a single pilot to stand on.  I’d venture a guess that the chief difficulty in all of these products is chiefly safety, because it’s incredibly easy to lose control of such a device and either seriously injure or kill yourself.
